# scrollTo Create a loop with index

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have got a wrapper with n elements. I want to avoid every adding a Click function for every element, and rather use a loop. How can this be achieved?

```
$("#wrapper .nav a.nav-1").click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo('#item1', 1000 );
    return false;
});

$("#wrapper .nav a.nav-2").click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo( '#item2', 1000 );
    return false;
});
$("#wrapper .nav a.nav-3").click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo( '#item3', 1000 );
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$("#wrapper .nav a").each(function(i, el){
    $(el).click(function() {
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo('#item' + (i+1), 1000 );
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: If you are going to do this, at least grab the class name, find the class that starts with `'nav'` and parse out the number.

Answer (score 0):

```
function warp(num) {
  $("#wrapper .nav a.nav-" + num).click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo('#item' + num, 1000 );
    return false;
  });
}
```

Assuming I understood you. You need to practice English more.

Comment: For a non-native (probably beginner) English speaker, it is quite understandable. Maybe OP is using SO to improve and practice English

Comment: @barts Are you looking at the original or the edited version? I was only able to understand him by reading the code. I could not understand the English at all.

Comment: I was looking at the original. No problem at all, but that might be because English is also not my native language, and I am used to communicate with Asian English speakers